# Font size rendered differently in Safari

Tags: size

Why is the same font size (16px) rendered so much smaller in Safari than in Firefox or Google Chrome, and how can I prevent this?  I've tried all the suggestions in previous answers to similar questions and nothing seems to work.

I have tried various resets with no effect.